# Getting error: ModelError: Received server error (500) error when hitting sage maker endpoint

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

```
`const callSageMaker = async () => { 

const client = new SageMakerRuntimeClient();
 let data = '0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0';
    const params = {
        EndpointName: process.env.SAGEMAKER_EP_NAME,
        ContentType: "text/plain",
        Body:'bytes',
        data,
    };
    const command = new InvokeEndpointCommand(params);
    try {
        const data = await client.send(command);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        // error handling.
        console.log('error catch',{ error });
        return error;
    }
}`
```

I am hitting this sageMaker endpoint but getting this error

` {
error: ModelError: Received server error (500) from primary with message "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">

500 Internal Server Error

## Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

{  
    '$fault': 'client',
    '$metadata': {
      httpStatusCode: 424,
      extendedRequestId: undefined,
      cfId: undefined,
      attempts: 1,
      totalRetryDelay: 0
    },
    OriginalStatusCode: 500,
    OriginalMessage: '\n' +
      '500 Internal Server Error\n' +
      '

## Internal Server Error

\n' +
      '

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

\n',
    ErrorCode: 'INTERNAL_FAILURE_FROM_MODEL'
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I was sending the data incorrectly correct format was

params{
Body:data
}